# Adding a 1d array in 2d array in java

Tags: java, arrays

I am writing a code where i have to add a 1d array in 2d array.
For example: I have a userlist array which will add data array in it

```
Double[][] userList =  new Double[4][appName.size()];
Double[] data = new Double[appName.size()];
```

so user list will have something like this:

```
userlist={{1,2,3,4},  {2,3,4,7},  {0,0,1,2,}}
```

where `{1,2,3,4}`===> represents data array.

Problem: The problem that i am getting is that each time what data array returns just overwrite the whole thing in userlist with the new data.

for example:

```
if userlist={{1,2,3,4},  {2,3,4,7}} and data returns {0,0,4,5}
then my userlist becomes: {{0,0,4,5}, {0,0,4,5}, {0,0,4,5} }.
```

Code:

```
Double[][] userList = null;
userList = new Double[4][appName.size()];
String prevName = null;
Double[] data = new Double[appName.size()];
int count=0;

   for(AuditInformationEntity e : auditInfoList)
   {
    //int count =0;

    if(prevName== null || !prevName.equals(e.getDisplayName()) )
    {

        if(prevName!=null)
        {

        ////====>> I think Something to be done here<========/////  
            userList[count++]=data;
        }
        //data = new ArrayList<Double>();
        for(int i = 0 ; i<appName.size();i++)
            data[i]=0d;
        prevName = e.getDisplayName();
    }
    Double d = data[appName.indexOf(e.getAppName())];

    if(d==null){
        d=1d;
        data[appName.indexOf(e.getAppName())]= d;
    }
    else
    {
        d++;
        data[appName.indexOf(e.getAppName())]= d;

    }


}
   userList[count++]=data;



       return userList;
```

Comment: Is this whole code in a method?

Comment: yes it is in a method..

Answer (score 1):

You've correctly identified the problem line. Java doesn't technically have multidimensional arrays; instead, it has arrays *of* arrays. This means that when you say `userList[i] = data`, you're just telling Java to update the reference of `userList[i]` to point to the same `data` array. (This is called an aliasing bug, since you are thinking you're dealing with different arrays, but you're just calling the same array by different names.)

Instead, in this case it's probably better to do this:

```
int i;
double userList[][] = new double[numberOfArrays][];
double data[] = new double[4];
...
    // inside a loop
    // read into data
    userList[i] = Arrays.copyOf(data);
```

This doesn't actually allocate the inside 4-element arrays when you create `userList`; it makes copies of each version of the `data` array when you're adding it.